# Convert a part of PDF to image file

Tags: python, image, api, pdf

I want to split the PDF document (that has a numbered list of questions) and export it to jpeg. There are many APIs for exporting a whole page of the document, but I want to export separate questions of question paper as an image in different folders per PDF in bulk. Some questions in the PDF document may contain images and equations.

Answer (score 0):

you will use adobe acrobat pro for your solution.

first, you will extract the pdf as separate files like the below images.

[image: Extract page]

[image: Extract page as separate files]

Then you will export the files as images like the below images.
[[image: export as jpg files3]

or you will use [Online PDF editor](https://www.ilovepdf.com/) for your solution